# При возвращении на экран (navigation Controller) c tableView выбранная ячейка остается серой

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На главном экране представлен tableView, так же реализован переход на другой экран при нажатии на ячейку, но при возвращении на первый экран ячейка остается серой

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от того, как у вас реализован переход на другой экран. Вы можете  вставить в начало функции

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

вызов

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

И тогда строка наверняка станет не выделенной.

Comment: Можете ли вы рассказать по подробнее про эту ошибку и от какого перехода она зависит? И конечно спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Ошибки нет. Просто можно вызвать переход через segue, тогда строка автоматически потеряет выделение. А можно сделать переход программно, через создание контроллера, и тогда нужно также программно снять выделение строки.

Answer (score -1):

В методе делегата при нажатии на ячейку, например, можно сделать так)

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```